# Do not remove trailing zero after fraction in xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

fractiondigits in xsd remove the trailing zero which I do not want.Please help

I am using below code to restrict my decimal value

```
<xs:simpleType name="Decimal_15_2">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:totalDigits value="15"/>
        <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Expecting result as

```
<principalAmount>500.00</principalAmount>
```

but actual output is

```
<principalAmount>500</principalAmount>
```

Comment: Actual output of what process? You've got a schema and an instance document but you haven't told us anything about what processing you are doing, with what software products.

Comment: It is TIBCO process where I am parsing a string into a XML.

Comment: Then you need to tag the question (or raise it on a forum) where people who know that software product will find it.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I found the solution using regEx. Cheers..!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the relevant TIBCO product specification says about this, but it isn't breaking any XSD rules. The fractionDigits facet restricts the value space, not the lexical space: `value='2'` means that the value must be an exact multiple of 0.01, not that the value must be written with two decimal digits. Your tool has generated output that is valid against your schema.

You can restrict the lexical space to contain two decimal digits using a `pattern` facet, but I very much doubt that any instance generator will take notice of that, since generating a string that conforms to a particular regular expression is a rather challenging task.

Answer (score 0):

As per W3C.org - Leading and Trailing zeros are optional for decimal data type.

Ref    - [W3C.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#decimal)
Read the article     - [SUPPRESSION OF LEADING AND TRAILING ZEROES IN TYPE R DECIMAL NUMBER](http://www.x12.org/rfis/Suppression%20of%20Leading%20and%20Trailing%20Zeroes%20in%20Type%20R%20Decimal%20Number.pdf)
Another article by IBM   - [standards rules for Leading or Trailing zeroes](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21517840)

Comment: Thank you.. But due to business requirement I have to keep trailing zeros although it is optional. I used simple regEx in schema to restrict my output. the pattern is <xs:pattern value="\d{0,15}\.?\d{0,2}"/>.